# What is the difference between द्विष and शत्रु in Puranic literature

Tags: durga-saptasati

I came across the word द्विष in Durgasapsati and I figured that it meant शत्रु. Is that true or is there a difference between the two?

Comment: no difference, they should be synonymous

Comment: द्विष means hatred not enemy. In one of the stotrams there is द्विषो जहि. Meaning destroy hatred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dviṣa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/dvis#sanskrit) cames from the root √dviṣ (“to hate”) and literally means “one who feels hatred towards another”.

[Śatru](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/shatru#sanskrit) comes from the root √śad (“to throw down”) and literally means “one who overthrows another”.

So yes, basically they mean the same, but in different context they might differ. Interestingly though, the Benfey Sanskrit-English Dictionary suggests the English word “hate” to be a cognate of Śatru.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the meanings of those 2 words in the online Sanskrit dictionary.  Both give the same meaning.

[द्विष](https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=dviSa&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) - Enemy, foe, hateful

[शत्रु](https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&tran_input=%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81&script=hk&anz=100&direct=au) - Enemy, foe, rival